# can I create udev rule to keep track of edac errors?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, udev

Need to call a script whenever edac error is thrown up by kernel/system.

I created following UDEV rule for this purpose, if the ce_count changes then I would like to
execute /var/tmp/test.sh, then I did "udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger" and
"udevadm monitor", also induced errors using mce-inect but the script didnt execute.

```
  cat /etc/udev/rules.d/98-edac.rules

  ACTION=="change", ATTR{ce_count},  KERNEL=="mc0", RUN+="/var/tmp/test.sh"  


  root@host0:/var/tmp# udevadm info -ap /sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0                             
  Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
  walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
  found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
  A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
  and the attributes from one single parent device.

 looking at device '/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0':
   KERNEL=="mc0"
   SUBSYSTEM=="mc0"
   DRIVER==""
   ATTR{ce_count}=="21"
   ATTR{ce_noinfo_count}=="0"
   ATTR{max_location}=="channel 7 slot 2 "
   ATTR{mc_name}=="Broadwell Socket#0"
   ATTR{seconds_since_reset}=="5223"
   ATTR{size_mb}=="65536"
   ATTR{ue_count}=="0"
   ATTR{ue_noinfo_count}=="0"

looking at parent device '/devices/system/edac/mc':
   KERNELS=="mc"
   SUBSYSTEMS=="edac"
   DRIVERS==""

looking at parent device '/devices/system/edac':
   KERNELS=="edac"
   SUBSYSTEMS==""
   DRIVERS==""

root@host0:/var/tmp# udevadm info -ap /sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0
```

'''

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.